# Mysql query and order meta value

Tags: wp-query, mysql, meta-query

I made a mysql query to WordPress like this:

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'where'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'london'
    LIMIT 0,50  ";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

In this way i can grab all posts with `meta_key = "where"` and `meta_value = london`

The problem is that I've also got another `meta_key`, `"date"` and a `meta_value` that contains the real date like `"05-06-2013"`, `"06-06-2013"`, etc.

How can I query all posts with meta `"where" = "london"` and order by date using the data contain in meta `"date" = "xx-xx-xxxx"` ?

Answer (score 1):

While the [`WPDB`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class, or its global `$wpdb` instance are your friend when it comes to querying custom tables or WP core data that does not have a higher-level API, it is overkill to use it to query posts.

Instead, read up on [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

In your case, you'd use it like so:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 50,    /* set limit to 50 */
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' ), /* fetch both posts and pages */
    'meta_key' => 'date',    /* garb only posts with meta_key "date" set */
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',    /* sort by numeric value of above key */
    'order' => 'ASC', /* sot order */
    'meta_query' => array(    /* grab only posts/pages w/ "london" as value for "where" */
        array(
            'key' => 'where',
            'value' => 'london',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$pageposts = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $pageposts->have_posts() ) :
    $pageposts->the_post();
    /* output something */
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

The above sorting by date will work flawlessly with either a timestamp or a `YYYY-MM-DD` string format.

With the way you currently have it, you will need an additional iteration...

Comment: There are some differences between the MySQL query in the question and your solution. At first, the MySQL query limits the number of results to 50. `-1` will return all results. And second, the MySQL query return all kind of posts (publish, trashed, draft, etc). Your solution returns only published posts/pages.

Comment: Set the limit to 50 now, obviously did not see that. But, @Ralf912, the latter point I assumed to be unwanted in the first place, given that the OP chose to call his variable holding the query results `$pageposts`...